# How to design a animated text box using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Need to design a Search box that is very similar to Stackoverflow.com header search. i.e, while cursor is placed it should expand and show button. will it be possible without using any script other than CSS and HTML ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the [pseudo class :focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:focus). You can make it bigger when focused:

```css
input{
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}
input:focus{
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

*Next time: You found a working example. If you use your debug console, you can inspect the elemt. Just check the styles/javascript before you focus it and then after you clicked it. Then it's just a comparion what changed.*

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  border: 1px solid #000;;
}
input:focus{
   width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
```

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but almost identical to the other (in this case mine). It's recommended not to post it again, unless you have new/other information. This answer is no additional information, thus not help the TS further :) (Not downvote worthy, but worth a note)

Comment: I'm on snippet, when other (in this case you) post their answer. If you say I can remove my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to the width of your input, and change the width when its on focus.

I have added search icon that can display when input is focused.

```css
#search {
  transition: width 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border:0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:5px;
}

#search:focus {
  width: 50%;
}

label
{
  padding:15px 10px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  display:none;
}

#search:focus ~ label
{
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search" /><label for="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
```

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, but almost identical to **two** others. It's recommended not to post it again, unless you have new/other information. This answer is no additional information, thus not help the TS further :) (Not downvote worthy, but worth a note)

Comment: haha, yes now your answer is a bit different. But now you've just added more styling, which doesnt matter anything for the actual question. Your solution is still exactly the same, now it's just with padding (just like the post by Black Panther, so still nothing new)